# how to remove item from json file with python

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I am programming a Discord bot for a Discord server but I have not found the way to delete an object from a `json` file. I have imported everything that I need to do this I think:

```
import discord
import json
from webserver import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.utils
import os
from discord import Game

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
  with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
      users = json.load(f)
      users.remove(member.id)
```

I am trying to delete the info about the leaving member. For example I am trying to delete `702036854253289512` from:

```
{
    "702036299242274876": {
        "Rank": 0,
        "komppevoice": 0
    },
    "702036854253289512": {
        "Rank": 0,
        "komppevoice": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: `del users[member.id]`. Also, you need to open the file with `'r'` (read) statement instead of `'w'` to load it first. Then open it up again with `'w'`, then use `json.dump(f)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no `remove` method on dictionaries I don't think. Second, you will need to re-save the file after editing.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
  with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
      users = json.load(f)

  del users[member.id]

  with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
      json.dump(users, f)
```

Comment: but this emptys the whole file

Comment: i only needed to put `del users[str(member.id)]` but now it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the key from the dictionary first and then save to the file.

You can remove a key from a dictionary with dict.pop or with del dicti[key].

```
users.pop(member.id)
```

or

```
del users[member.id]
```

Comment: this is the problem its emptying the whole file `{
    "702036299242274876": {
        "Rank": 0,
        "komppevoice": 0
    },
    "702036854253289512": {
        "Rank": 0,
        "komppevoice": 0
    }
}`
and if someone lefts the file is empty

Comment: Can you print the dictionary before and after the pop or del commands?

Answer (score 0):

Using `del users[member.id]` as nighthawk454 suggests will cause KeyError exception being thrown if `member.id` is not in the file, so use it only if you sure that `member.id` is there or handle exception:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
try:
    del users[member.id]
    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
except KeyError as exc:
    log.warning(f"Member {member.id} is missing in users.json")
```

Other option would be to use [`dict.pop(key, [default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop), which doesn't raise error if you provide default value:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    removed_user = users.pop(member.id, None)
    if removed_user:
        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
```

Comment: yes, or `if member.id in users` would also work. arguably more pythonic.

Comment: i am sure it is in there because its user id what does not change

Comment: @Crazycrafter227 in this case use answer from nighthawk454

Comment: it gives with @nighthawk454 new example `keyerror` `Ignoring exception in on_member_remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-package
s/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 40, in on_member_remove
    del users[member.id]
KeyError: 702036854253289512`

Comment: @Crazycrafter227 Well, your file is empty at the time you open it. Make sure your file contains users data. Here's an example https://pastebin.com/bdBUQvpU

Comment: @I.Yegor that is what i have right now but it gives `KeyError`

The `KeyError` is `Ignoring exception in on_member_remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-package
s/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 42, in on_member_remove
    del users[member.id]
KeyError: 702036854253289512`
and i even check if the member is not on the list so it would just ignore it and not to try delete it